# jupyterを特定のconda環境の中から起動 vs. conda環境の外から起動

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda, jupyter-lab

`jupyter`(`notebook`や、`lab`）を、**特定の`conda`環境の中から起動**すると、問題なく使用できるのですが、
**`conda`環境の外から起動**した場合、カーネルの選択時に下記のエラーが出ます。
（`jupyter`まわりの挙動がよく理解できておらず・・・かなり調べましたが苦戦しています）

この現象は、何が原因だと推測できるでしょうか。
お力貸していただきたく。

```
.
.
  File "C:\Users\shinji\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

---

- **特定の`conda`環境の中から起動**

*コマンドプロンプト*にて,

```
C:\Users\shinji\dir> activate my_env
(my_env) C:\Users\shinji\dir> jupyter lab
```

jupyter lab起動後,
Select kernel: `my_env`

---

- **`conda`環境の外から起動**

*コマンドプロンプト*にて,

```
C:\Users\shinji\dir> jupyter lab
```

jupyter lab起動後,
Select kernel: `my_env`

---

ちなみに、`Anaconda Prompt`ではなく、通常のコマンドプロンプトを使用。
OSは`Windows 10`です。

Comment: この辺の記事を読み解くと参考になるかも。[How to use Jupyter notebooks in a conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58068818/9014308), [Link Conda environment with Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37433363/9014308), [In which conda environment is Jupyter executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37085665/9014308)

Comment: 他にはこんな記事が参考になるかも。[1発実行！仮想環境×Jupyter実行バッチの作り方！](https://www.lisz-works.com/entry/jupyter-pyenv-bat)

Answer (score 0):

すでに解決しているかもしれませんが、同様と思われる問題をPATHの追加で解決したので、記載します。

現象としては、
・anaconda promptからはjupyter notebookが起動できる。
・他の環境(自分の場合はgit bash)からjupyter notebookを起動しようとすると、冒頭のエラーが出る。

その対応は、
・以下を環境変数のPATHに追加。ただし、xxxはanacondaへのパス。
xxx\Anaconda3;xxx\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;xxx\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;xxx\Anaconda3\Library\bin;xxx\Anaconda3\Scripts;xxx\Anaconda3\bin;xxx\Anaconda3\condabin;

その結果
・他の環境(自分の場合はgit bash)でもjupyter notebookを起動できる。

この対応に至った経緯
・anaconda promptがどのように起動されているかを確認。
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'xxx\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'xxx\Anaconda3' "
・conda-hook.ps1を確認し、それから呼ばれている、Conda.psm1の
Add-Sys-Prefix-To-Path()にあるパスを追加。

他にも処理がされているようですが、それは詳細確認できていません。

anacondaインストール時にデフォルト設定で行ったため、"PATHを通す"にチェックが
入っていなかったことが原因のような気もしています。